# How to simulate a system-wide touch event using iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, automated-tests

Does anybody know how can we simulate a system-wide touch event under iOS 7?

We used the following code that once worked for iOS 6 or older:

```
CGPoint location = .... ;

struct GSTouchEvent {
    GSEventRecord record;
    GSHandInfo    handInfo;
    GSPathInfo    pathInfo;
    uint32_t      newIn6;
} * event = (struct GSTouchEvent*) &touchEvent;

bzero(touchEvent, sizeof(touchEvent));
event->record.type = kGSEventHand;
event->record.windowLocation = location;
event->record.timestamp = _GSCurrentEventTimestamp();
event->record.infoSize = sizeof(GSHandInfo) + sizeof(GSPathInfo);
event->handInfo.type = getHandInfoType(0, 1);
event->handInfo.pathInfosCount = 1;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathIndex     = 1;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathIdentity  = 2;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathProximity = 0x03 ;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathLocation  = location;

GSSendEvent((GSEventRecord*)event,  port);
```

Comment: Explain what have you tried so far?? what does you mean by system-wide touch event? Do you want to capture all touch events in the app and do something for that??

Comment: Under previous versions of iOS, we had an application that sent touch events using the GSEvent Framework. This framework does not work anymore under iOS7. Such an event would execute a touch, regardless of the topmost application and would work even if the Springboard is being displayed.

Comment: Add code that you were/are using..

Comment: @מנשהסולקיס did you find any solution? Please let me know I am facing same issue.